# Framerate on AIR for Android - Actionscript 3

Tags: android, flash, actionscript-3

I am currently working on making Android apps using AIR for Android.

This is a sample file and package that I am running to test the FPS and Memory usage of my application while it is not even doing anything,

it appears to hit flat at
6,975,488
FPS: 
0

Which from what I can work out is 7 megabytes and a frame rate of 1/0 frames per second...

I was wondering if anyone could help me improve the way I write as3 in order to improve this and get my framerate back up to scratch.

Also I was wondering if people thought it was generally better to mix timeline and package coding or stick to just package/class coding.

Been working on this and my other file for a few days now, I am hoping to get some sleep and solve it in the morning as I know this file is a mess and that there is way too much going on in one file, but I thought after having cut everything out except the base key functions as well as leaving the memory/fps tracer there would bring the fps back up to 60 but it does not appear to have done so.

I have also noticed a blank AIR template running the mem/fps test seems to hit 60fps no problem, I guess I will just have to trace out that data 24/7 while developing so as to keep on top of it.

I apologise because I know my coding is terrible and probably very messy/poorly written.

Thank you for any help in advance.

```
package com.qr.maze{
import flash.desktop.NativeApplication
import flash.desktop.SystemIdleMode;
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
import flash.ui.Keyboard;
import flash.utils.getTimer;
import flash.system.System;
[SWF(width="480",height="800",frameRate="60",backgroundColor="#000000")]
public class menu extends MovieClip{

    public function menu(){
        NativeApplication.nativeApplication.systemIdleMode=SystemIdleMode.KEEP_AWAKE;
        NativeApplication.nativeApplication.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN,keyOn);
        NativeApplication.nativeApplication.addEventListener(Event.ACTIVATE,onActivate);
        NativeApplication.nativeApplication.addEventListener(Event.DEACTIVATE,onDeactivate);
        NativeApplication.nativeApplication.addEventListener(Event.EXITING,onDeactivate);
        this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,performMemTest);
        this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,performFrameTest);
    }protected function keyOn(e:KeyboardEvent):void{
        if(e.keyCode==Keyboard.BACK){e.preventDefault();}
        else if(e.keyCode==Keyboard.HOME){onDeactivate(null);}
        else if(e.keyCode==Keyboard.MENU){e.preventDefault();}
    }protected function onActivate(e:Event):void{}
    protected function onDeactivate(e:Event):void{NativeApplication.nativeApplication.exit();}
    public function performMemTest(e:Event):void{trace(System.totalMemory);}
    public function performFrameTest(e:Event):void{
        var prevTimer:Number=0;
        var curTimer:Number=0;
        var frames:int;
        frames+=1;
        curTimer=getTimer();
        if(curTimer-prevTimer>=1000){
            trace("FPS: "); trace(Math.round(frames*1000/(curTimer-prevTimer)));
                prevTimer=curTimer;
                frames=0;
        }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It appears I was just being tired and overworking on the file after having got some sleep and re made the file in timeline I am maintaining a steady memory usage and steady framerate, but the framerate appears to differ heavily on the Android Device.

I will continue working on this.

Comment: Dude! Does AIR actually work for Android devices? I thought AIR was just for desktop, while normal Flex builds for android, ios, and web...

Comment: AIR works for mobile (Android & iOS) too.